# XMPP Python 3

Tags: python, xmpp

Какие модули есть для 3-тего Python'a для работы с протоколом xmpp?

Answer (score 1):

[xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Он пойдет к 3 Питону?

Answer (score 0):

Twsited.words, когда допилят до совместимости с Python3. А зачем Python3?